# Fragments vs AsyncTask vs IntentService vs Longrunning operations

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have the following design:

Activity/FragmentA upon a user action starts an AsyncTask to fetch a set of data.
While the AsyncTask is running, a progress indicator is displayed to the user.
When the AsyncTask finishes its task and fetches the resultset, it saves it in a singleton class serving as a shared datamodel.

When FragmentA is notified that the AsyncTask has finished (LocalBroadcastReceiver) then it start `ActivityB/FragmentB` which takes the set of results from the shared singleton and displays them in a ListView.

This works but since I am a newbie in android I am trying to understand and learn best practices.
E.g. I see a small delay from the time the progress bar is dismissed to the time the UI of ActivityB/FragmentB is displayed (during this latency the UI of ActivityA/FragmentA is still visible).
Also I think that somehow if the fetch of the items was done from FragmentB instead of FragmentA would make FragmentB "autonomous"
Overall can someone please help me understand how could I have implemented this differently using better/standard practices in android and the pros/cons of each approach?

Comment: I just learned recently that Fragments should be avoided: https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html so if you want to learn best practices, this may is an option.

Answer (score 1):

**Fragments**

Fragments are small part of the activity which has their own life cycle, which provides developer more flexibility to deal with UI. Fragments has nothing to do with background processes.

Now your main question is about the background processes.

**AsyncTask**

This is nothing but the bit better version of thread with some predefined callbacks, when u need to perform some network operation which will take not more than 20 seconds, and after that it refreshes the UI, its better to use asycntask. Do not use Services (Avoid complexity, Keep it simple). You can use some third party library also.

**IntentService**

Now IntentService are better version of service, the main purpose of IntentService is to avoid performing long running operations on mainthread and provide queueing system to the developer. You should use services if you do not need user interaction while running long running operations (e.g syncing app with the server at the end of every day).

So for conclusion

- User Interaction + short running network operation = AsyncTask
- No User Interaction + long running network operation = IntentService + Broadcast Receiver to notify UI of needed

Comment: What about Handlers and Loopers? I am confused of so many classes that seems to do the same thing

Comment: They are more like for messaging mechanism for threads. Handlers provide very much control than aynctasks